# SQL query to retrieve conversations from messages?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get conversations from my private messages table with a single elegant SQL query. Here's a simplified version of my table:

[image: Sample table]

Let's say I want to retrieve all James's conversations. The lines highlighted in green are the ones I want him to have in his inbox. In other words, I want to select the latest messages james has received, grouped by sender. I've tried the following query :

```
SELECT *
FROM "messages"
WHERE To = "James"
ORDER BY Id DESC
GROUP BY `From`
```

But MySQL returns me these rows :

[image: Sample table]

So how could I fix this request ?

Thanks !

**EDIT**: I Shouldn't have used "From" as a field name, I won't change it now to avoid  breaking the answers but sorry about that.

Comment: `SELECT * ... GROUP BY From` stop doing this. Learn how to use `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT M.Id,
   M.`From`,
   M.`To`,
   M.message
FROM messages M
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT `from`, max(Id) as maxId
     FROM messages
     WHERE `to` = "James"
     GROUP BY `from`)T
ON M.Id = T.maxId
```

You say you want messages that 'James' has received but you compare `from = 'James'` is that a mistake?

Edit: @Lotharyx wanted to know if there's a way to do it without a subquery, so here's one way. see second query in this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ca076/5/1)

```
SELECT IF(@prevFrom IS NULL OR @prevFrom != M.`From`,@row:=1,@row:=@row +1) as row,
       @prevFrom:=M.`From`,
       M.id, M.`From`, M.`To`, M.message
FROM messages M
WHERE `to` = 'James'
HAVING row = 1
ORDER BY M.`From`, M.Id DESC;
```

Comment: Ha, yes this was a mistake, sorry about that.

Comment: i made a typo `M.message` not `M.messages`

Comment: apparently `To` is also a reserved word

Comment: You need: `ON M.Id = T.maxId AND M.\`From\` = T.\`From\` WHERE M.\`To\` = 'James'` - unless `id` is the Primary Key (which I guess is your assumption.)

Comment: This query is senselessly complex.  There's no need for an inner join or a subquery.  Mysql has a LIMIT clause.  Simply select from the table, order by ID, and limit to the top X results, for however many you want.

Comment: @Lotharyx, the OP wanted the lastest message for each sender. How would your query look without a subquery? I would like to know too!

Comment: NICE! Notice how the second approach results in a much simpler execution plan.  It's still an eye-bending query, and I still have this gut feeling there must be a simpler way, but my hat is off to you, sir!

Comment: yeah it's weird that you have to specify `HAVING` before the `ORDER BY` because of syntax, but the `ORDER BY` is done before the `HAVING` is applied.

Answer (score 1):

From is a reserved word, enclose it with backticks.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Ha, thanks for pointing this out. This is not my real table actually, just a simplified version but I should have used another key.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a GROUP BY clause, as you're not using an aggregating function.  Remove it and you should get the results you want.  Someone else suggested a query featuring a self-join and subquery, which is needlessly complex.

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `To` = 'James' ORDER BY `Id` DESC LIMIT 5
```

That'll give you the 5 most recent messages to James.  Change the LIMIT argument as needed.

Note that `LIMIT` is a mysql-specific extension, but you tagged with mysql so I presume that is the engine you are using.

Comment: this won't give the OP the highlighted green rows.

Comment: Somehow I totally missed the "grouped by sender" requirement in the question.  You're right, my answer is totally useless.  :(  I'm convinced there's a way to do it without using a subquery, though...  I must find it!

Comment: If you find it, comment and let me know! I would love to know too.

Comment: I found a way to do it without subquery, but it uses variables. see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

should be like this instead

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE `From` = 'James' ORDER BY Id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but in case someone else has a similar doubt, this was my solution:

> Assuming James has the ID 1 (I use ID but feel free to replace 1 with
>   "James" a username, an ID, etc.)

```
SELECT IF(`from` = 1, `to`, `from`) AS `friend_id`, `message`, `created_at` 
FROM `messages` 
WHERE `from` = 1 OR  `to` = 1
GROUP BY friend_id
ORDER BY `created_at`  DESC
```

I'm not sure if this is the best possible solution, but it fetches the right messages. The trick was to use an IF to get the friend_id (it can be in the "from" or in the "to" column